# Pyrogram | Python Import Error

Tags: python, pip

```
from asyncio import sleep
from Pyrogram import Client, filters #pip install tgcrypto, pip install pyrogram 


app = Client("my_account")
spam_text = 'spam'
delay = 0.25


@app.on_message(filters.command('spam', prefixes='.') & filters.me)
async def enable_spam(_, message):
    await message.delete()
    cmd = message.text.split()
    for i in range(int(cmd[1])):
        await message.reply_text(spam_text)
        await sleep(delay)

app.run()
```

> pip не помогает, незнаю что делать *-Я устанавливал модуль!-*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ilyas\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Bomber Telegram\main.py", li
ne 2, in <module>
    from Pyrogram import Client, filters #pip install tgcrypto, pip insta
ll pyrogram
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pyrogram'
```

Comment: вторую строку замени на `from pyrogram import Client, filters`

Comment: Удалите старую версию Python(Если она есть), и вообще удалите python и установите заново. Обязательно при установке ставьте галку на ADD PATH. Если есть старая версия python, его удаление возможно поможет

Comment: У меня была проблема - установки пакетов в пустоту... оказалось на рабочем месте было три версии python и куда и как это все ставилось, только ITГосподу известно(если такой есть)

Comment: а вы куда качаете библиотеку? есть у меня подозрение на неправильное расположение библиотеки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подозреваю, что Вы немного ошиблись с именем импортируемого модуля: если судить по странице модуля на [`PyPI`](https://pypi.org/project/Pyrogram/), нужно его вызывать со **строчной** буквы, вот так:

```py
from pyrogram import Client, filters # Pyrogram -> pyrogram
```

И да, первый данную идею предложил товарищ @ZxNuClear, так что + ему в карму :)

Comment: не помогает....

Comment: @SoftwareSec пытались устанавливать данный модуль через pip? Выложите дополнительные данные в сам вопрос

Comment: конечно я устанавливал

Comment: А какая тогда ошибка появляется?

Comment: та что и написана в вопросе

Comment: Попробуйте в таком случае переустановить модуль: `pip uninstall pyrogram     pip install pyrogram`

Comment: я только что попробовал не помогло

Comment: Здесь шанс велик того, что вы используете virtual environment, а ставите в общий стек. Или же у вас разные версии интерпретатора установлены. Деталей вы не пишете.

Comment: @void разные интерпритаторы

Comment: Ну тогда ставьте в тот, который используется для проекта вашего.

Comment: @4500zenja я награждаю тебя